# Unix filesystem hook

Tags: unix, filesystems, hook

I'd like to add a hook to the file system, so I can execute a process whenever a specific file is read from disk.  Does *nix provide a way to create such a hook? (I have root access)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en), based on [inotify](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=about&lang=en), implements just such a hook in a cron-like way. Unfortunately, it is Linux-specific, not generic to UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

If you run Solaris 10 or newer, an OpenSolaris based distribution, FreeBSD, (a recent) NetBSD or MacOS X, a dtrace script will easily do that job.